# How can I speed up the generation of an MP4 using matplotlib's Animation Writer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am using matplotlib to generate a graphical animation of some data. The data has about 4 hours of collection time so I expect the animation to be about 4 hours. However, generating a smaller 60 second video takes approximately 15 minutes. Thus, the total estimated run time for generating the 4 hour video is 2.5 days. I assume I am doing something incredibly inefficient. How can I speed up the creation of an animation with matplotlib?

### create_graph.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

matplotlib.use("Agg")

frame = pd.read_csv("tmp/total.csv")
min_time = frame.iloc[0]["time"]
max_time = frame.iloc[-1]["time"]
total_time = max_time - min_time

hertz_rate = 50
window_length = 5
save_count = hertz_rate * 100

def data_gen():
    current_index_of_matching_ts = 0
    t = data_gen.t
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < save_count:
        print("Done: {}%".format(cnt/save_count*100.0))
        predicted = cnt * (1.0/hertz_rate)
        while frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["time"] - min_time <= predicted and current_index_of_matching_ts < len(frame) - 1:
            current_index_of_matching_ts = current_index_of_matching_ts + 1

        y1 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var1"]
        y2 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var2"]
        y3 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var3"]
        y4 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var4"]
        y5 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var5"]
        y6 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var6"]
        y7 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var7"]
        y8 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var8"]
        y9 = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["var9"]
        t = frame.iloc[current_index_of_matching_ts]["time"] - min_time
        # adapted the data generator to yield both sin and cos
        yield t, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9
        cnt+=1

data_gen.t = 0

# create a figure with two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8, ax9) = plt.subplots(9,1,figsize=(7,14)) # produces a video of 700 × 1400

# intialize two line objects (one in each axes)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=2, color='b')
line2, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2, color='b')
line3, = ax3.plot([], [], lw=2, color='b')
line4, = ax4.plot([], [], lw=2, color='g')
line5, = ax5.plot([], [], lw=2, color='g')
line6, = ax6.plot([], [], lw=2, color='g')
line7, = ax7.plot([], [], lw=2, color='r')
line8, = ax8.plot([], [], lw=2, color='r')
line9, = ax9.plot([], [], lw=2, color='r')
line = [line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7, line8, line9]

# the same axes initalizations as before (just now we do it for both of them)
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8,  ax9]:
    ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
    ax.grid()

# initialize the data arrays 
xdata, y1data, y2data, y3data, y4data, y5data, y6data, y7data, y8data, y9data = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

my_gen = data_gen()
for index in range(hertz_rate*window_length-1):
    t, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9 = my_gen.__next__()
    xdata.append(t)
    y1data.append(y1)
    y2data.append(y2)
    y3data.append(y3)
    y4data.append(y4)
    y5data.append(y5)
    y6data.append(y6)
    y7data.append(y7)
    y8data.append(y8)
    y9data.append(y9)


def run(data):
    # update the data
    t, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9 = data
    xdata.append(t)
    y1data.append(y1)
    y2data.append(y2)
    y3data.append(y3)
    y4data.append(y4)
    y5data.append(y5)
    y6data.append(y6)
    y7data.append(y7)
    y8data.append(y8)
    y9data.append(y9)

    # axis limits checking. Same as before, just for both axes
    for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8, ax9]:
        ax.set_xlim(xdata[-1]-5.0, xdata[-1])

    # update the data of both line objects
    line[0].set_data(xdata, y1data)
    line[1].set_data(xdata, y2data)
    line[2].set_data(xdata, y3data)
    line[3].set_data(xdata, y4data)
    line[4].set_data(xdata, y5data)
    line[5].set_data(xdata, y6data)
    line[6].set_data(xdata, y7data)
    line[7].set_data(xdata, y8data)
    line[8].set_data(xdata, y9data)

    return line

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, my_gen, blit=True, interval=20, repeat=False, save_count=save_count)

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=hertz_rate, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
ani.save('lines.mp4', writer=writer)
```

Comment: You want 4 hours (=14400 seconds) of video at a rate of 50 Hertz? That would be 720000 frames in total. I suspect that this just floods your memory until it's full and then becomes really slow because it constantly needs to shuffle back end forth between the swap file and RAM.

Comment: It is writing one frame at a time. The performance seems to scale, it is just really slow to begin with.

Comment: I somehow lack the indication that should be faster than observed.

Comment: If i made a realtime graph and took a screen recording, it would be faster. That being said, it might be impossible due to individual frame rending used by matplotlib but there should be faster solutions,  I imagine.

Comment: I mean `mpeg` is a compressed data format, so encoding time isn't related to the time it takes to display a bunch of pixels.

Comment: What I would do is to check how long it takes to save one frame of your animation to a buffer. `buffer = io.BytesIO();  savefig(buffer)`. Then you know how long it takes just to render the image. The rest of the time is taken to create the video via `ffmpeg`. This allows to see whether the bottleneck is in matplotlib or ffmpeg.

Comment: Is this just a wrapper for the `ffmpeg` cli tool? If yes, and you find that `ffmpeg` is the bottleneck, then show the actual `ffmpeg` command being executed and the complete log from that process. Then we can give suggestions to potentially make it faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am answering my own question here so if you find this enjoy!

Here are some facts

- matplotlib creates high quality graphs
- matplotlib generates graphs slowly relative to some other libraries like [PyQWT](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/) (c++ bindings are used for speed)
- Generating a real time graph of 4 hours of data would take about 20 hours on my mac.

To solve my issue, I created separate files and later joined them together. I used the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library.

### generate_graphs.py

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
from make_video_graph_mp4 import write_chart_to_file_wrapper


total_parts = 6

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #spawn is critical to not share plt across threads.
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    with Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(write_chart_to_file_wrapper, [[i, total_parts] for i in range(total_parts)]))
```

### make_video_graph_mp4.py

```
def write_chart_to_file(my_part, parts):
    # ... code to create part my_part/parts of the video.
    Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
    writer = Writer(fps=hertz_rate, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
    filename = 'out/videos/{}-lines{}-{}.mp4'.format(band_name, start_index, end_index)        
    ani.save(filename, writer=writer, dpi=100)
```